# Valid state in State Machines MDriven

Tags: mdriven

What defines a valid value for different states in a State Machine in MDriven?

I am doing a simple, or not so simple information system on a warehouse database (imo). I want my system to be able to describe if my product is either "On its way from supplier", "In stock" or "Sent to customer". Also, what should define the "start" & "end" state (the start and end points/dots)?

Answer (score 0):

Broad question - but keep in mind you can have multiple state attributes and not everything is packed into one process (one process per state-machine).

Models are what you make them; the something-state of a thing is a term that describe that current situation - maybe OrderReceived-Packed-Shipped-ShipmentReceived.

The start-state is usually not occupied very long  - if there are no guards that stop it to move to the next valid state it will move on object creation.

The stop-state is not always added to the state machine - but if it is - and when it is reached the object is deleted upon entry. Most systems do not want to delete things - they will want to keep records of old stuff.